# MongoDB-PHP search in external json file?

Tags: php, json, mongodb, mongodb-query, embed

I am trying to make a simple search bar for a cinema website, using PHP and Mongo as database.

The search bar HTML code:

```
<!-- Search bar -->
<form action="searchbar.php" method="get">
    <input placeholder="Search for movie" type="text" name="search">
        <button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

I have a  "moviedb.json" file with all the movies in the database (shortened so it's easier to read):

```
[
   {
      "movieName" : "12 STRONG"
   },   
   {
      "movieName" : "Black Panthers"
   }
]
```

Now my "searchbar.php" file looks like this:

```
<?php
//connect to mongod
$mongoClient = new MongoClient();
//select mongod workplace
$db = $mongoClient->cinevue;
$collection = $db->movie_list;



//pull json data in
$contents = file_get_contents('./moviedb.json');
//decode the json into php
$json = json_decode($contents, true);
//inseart json file into mongo collection
$collection->insert($json);


//get data from html search bar, securely
$search = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'search', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
//search in mongodb 
$finder = $db->movie_list->find(array("search" => $search));


// display results
echo "<h1>Movies Available:</h1>";
foreach ($finder as $match) {
    echo "<p>";
    echo "<Movies: " . $match['search'];
    echo "</p>";
}



//close mongod  
$mongoClient->close();
?>
```

THE RESULT OF THIS:

It does not perform a search for my input, into the actual "moviedb.json" file.

All I want is a search bar that searched in my external json file that contains the data to queried. I am not sure how to approach this. I have spend hours Googling :D

Comment: Just a question, why would you want to query an external file if you store your movies in MongoDB ?

Comment: Isn't that how mongoDB stores data?...I must be on the wrong track..

Comment: MongoDB store data as a document, not in a document. If you want to query your db, you need to use the php driver for mongo, check the documentation : http://php.net/manual/fr/class.mongodb.php